# Is this Java double-parsing behavior according to spec?

Tags: java, parsing, double, number-formatting

The `java.lang.Double.parseValue` method handles strangely-crafted representations of doubles in an inconsistent way.

If you write a very large number, so large that it is outside of `double`'s range, but then append a large negative exponent to bring it back in range, you end up in range (illustrated here in Scala's REPL):

```
scala>
java.lang.Double.parseDouble("10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000001e-400")
res25: Double = 1.0E-21
```

On the other hand, if you write a very tiny number, so small that it is outside of `double`'s range, but then use a large positive exponent to bring it back in range, it only works if the exponent itself is not too large:

```
scala> 
java.lang.Double.parseDouble("0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000001e400")
res26: Double = Infinity

scala>
java.lang.Double.parseDouble("0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000001e200")
res27: Double = 1.0E-179
```

Is this simply a bug, or is there a spec somewhere that allows this behavior, or are all of these allowed by spec to fail and one should just thank one's blessings when one gets the correct result?  (If it's a bug, has it been fixed?)

(Aside: I was writing custom String-to-double code and was going to defer to the Java default implementation for tricky cases, but this test case failed.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's almost certainly not in the spec. The corresponding section about [Floating-Point Literals in the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2) only specifies the *values* of the floating point literals. But it does not speak about valid *representations* of them.

Of course, there have to be limits. No one would expect that a string like

```
String s = "0.00... (3 billion zeros) ...001e3000000000";
```

to be parsed to `1.0`. But obviously, the limits are much lower here.

This example shows the limit:

```
public class DoubleTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        runTest(300, 324);
        runTest(300, 325);
        runTest(300, 326);
    }

    private static void runTest(int negativeExponent, int exponent)
    {
        String s = prefix(negativeExponent)+"1e"+exponent+"D";
        double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
        System.out.println(
            "For 1e-"+negativeExponent+" * 1e"+exponent+" result is "+d);
    }

    private static String prefix(int negativeExponent)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("0.");
        for (int i=0; i<negativeExponent; i++)
        {
            sb.append("0");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

It prints

> For 1e-300 * 1e324 result is 9.999999999999999E22
>
> For 1e-300 * 1e325 result is 1.0E24
>
> For 1e-300 * 1e326 result is Infinity

In fact, it is primarily related to the *exponent* being used. The relevant part that causes this bailout is in [FloatingDecimal.java, line 1996](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/tl/jdk/file/183a8c520b4a/src/share/classes/sun/misc/FloatingDecimal.java#l1996).

Answer (score 14):

I think its an edge case, but also a bug.  A simpler example is

```
String text = "0.000000000000000001e326";
System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(text));
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(text).doubleValue());
```

which prints in Java 7 update 25 and Java 8 update 5

```
Infinity
1.0E308
```

The BigDecimal parsing and convert to double shows this number is representable.

Comment: This might lead to a simple solution. Directly parse the common cases where the exponent is in-range, but use `new BigDecimal(text).doubleValue()` for the edge cases.

Answer (score 9):

It is a bug, but looking at the implementation Oracle might say it's *as designed*.

The way [it's implemented](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/2d585507a41b/src/share/classes/sun/misc/FloatingDecimal.java#l1255) is that the leading `kDigits` are converted to a long int.  As such, in the first example, the *calculated* exponent is within the `Double` range and it happily returns the result if it falls within the range.

For the second case, it'd figure the exponent is greater than the [maximum decimal exponent](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/2d585507a41b/src/share/classes/sun/misc/FloatingDecimal.java#l1371) and return infinity.

For the third case, it'd [reach here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/2d585507a41b/src/share/classes/sun/misc/FloatingDecimal.java#l1379) and returns the expected result.

Although the links above point to source for OpenJDK 6, it's unlikely that they would have *touched* the source in question for JDK 7 and 8.

Parsing doubles has traditionally been [fun](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/security/alert-cve-2010-4476-305811.html).  No surprises at the oddities in this case.

Comment: I think that the actual bailout is already caused in the `readJavaFormatString` method, and not in the `doubleValue` method. The latter only returns infinity due to the information that it was intentionally fed with by the former. But I agree: It looks like fun. The `FloatingDecimal` class contains the word **"Hack"** 9 (nine!) times, and lots of other rather colloquial-sounding comments ("Let's face it..", "HUMBUG"...). I would not touch this with a ten-foot pole either...

Comment: @Marco13 Did you look at the _fun_ link?  That was probably one bug that Oracle did fix.

Comment: @Marco13 Oh, BTW, doesn't really seem to do anything in there.  It bails out of this one only in case when there is something wrong with the input, i.e. if there is a _parsing_ issue.  As usual, look for the funny comments for sheer entertainment.

Comment: Parsing doubles is hard, really hard; there are some _foul_ gotchas. Printing them parsimoniously is even harder…